# How to initialize a class with a const pointer on a data object

Tags: c++

I have problems with initializing a class instance of the following type:

```
Object::Object(const double &a, const double &b, bool c, const uint8_t *data)
```

I try it in the following way:

```
a = 50;
b = 40;
c = false;
data_ = std::make_unique<uint8_t[]>(a*b);
Object a = Object(a, b, c, data);
```

and I get this error message:

```
no matching function for call to ‘namespace::Object::Object(double&, double&, bool&, std::unique_ptr<unsigned char []>&)’
```

The problem is probably this const pointer on an array.
Does someone know how to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to pass a [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) object where a raw `const uint8_t*` is expected.  That will not work, as `unique_ptr` is not implicitly convertible to a pointer.  However, you can use the [`unique_ptr::get()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/get) method to access the pointer it is holding.

On a sidenote, you have 2 different variables with the same `a` name.  You need to rename one of them.

Try this:

```cpp
double a = 50;
double b = 40;
bool c = false;
auto data = std::make_unique<uint8_t[]>(a*b);
Object obj(a, b, c, data.get());
```